# shell: how to replace a string with a new string containing a space

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a txt file with the following content:

```
hello my name 
is teddy bear, 
I like 
eating sweet honey!
```

I'd like to replace the line `is teddy bear` to `is sleepy bear`, with shell script.

I was trying the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

ORI_LINE="is[[:space:]]teddy[[:space:]]bear"
NEW_LINE="is[[:space:]]sleepy[[:space:]]bear"

eval sed -i -e 's/$ORI_LINE/$NEW_LINE/g' ./hello.txt
```

But at the end I got

```
hello my name 
is[[:space:]]sleepy[[:space:]]bear, 
I like 
eating sweet honey!
```

in which the `[[:space:]]` was not resolved to a real space.

I'd like to keep using variables `ORI_LINE` and `NEW_LINE`, instead of use the strings inline of the sed command.

Thanks!

Comment: sed  -e 's/is teddy bear/is sleppy bear/g' hello.txt

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you told it to put that pattern in. The replacement string should have actual spaces, not regex patterns that can match various types of "spaces" characters.

So, if

```
$: txt="hello my name is teddy bear,
I like eating sweet honey!"
$: ORI_LINE="is[[:space:]]teddy[[:space:]]bear"
$: NEW_LINE="is sleepy bear"
```

then

```
$: sed "s/$ORI_LINE/$NEW_LINE/g" <<< "$txt"
hello my name is sleepy bear,
I like eating sweet honey!
```